# Android 8 not sending timely Bluetooth events when in Doze/ App Standby mode

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth

I am attempting to create an app, using Ionic v1 and Cordova, the purpose of which is to maintain a connection to a bluetooth LE device and notify the user if it disconnects (along with trying to reconnect etc).  I am using the bluetooth plugin found here: https://github.com/randdusing/ng-cordova-bluetoothle

However during testing on Android 8.0 I've found that the OS doesn't fire the appropriate callback upon disconnection in anything like a timely fashion (it seems to wait until the next OS maintenance window, as explained here: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) when the device is in a Doze/ App Standby mode.  See example below:

```
$cordovaBluetoothLE.connect({
    address: address,
    timeout: timeout
}).then(
    null, // there is no "resolve" callback, this promise uses the "notify" callback on connection state change instead
    function(e) {
        return onConnectError(e);
    }, 
    function(result) { // this does not happen in a timely way when device is dozing
        if(result.status === "connected") {
            onConnected(result);
        } else {
            onDisconnected(result);
        }
    }
);
```

I have tried the following (on a Moto G6 running Android 8.0):

- I have set our app to run in background mode using these plugins:

  - https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode
  - https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-background-mode-bluetooth-central
- I have manually turned off battery optimizations specifically for this app via Settings > Battery > Battery Optimization

So, how do we get Android 8 to notify us as immediately as possible when a Bluetooth disconnection happens?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question? If so I would be interested.

Comment: @JasonSchot Have you found a solution to handle such case? Even I am looking for answers to a similar problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056998/keep-app-working-even-when-phone-is-locked-sleep-ionic4